# @version with timestamp in super class throwing error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using @version for a date field in super class and it is extended by subclass.
While querying the db i am getting exception like

Object references an unsaved transient instance.save the transient instance before flushing.

If i remove @version it not throwing any exception

Comment: Is your version field exists in database ?

Comment: @JEY yes it exists

Comment: Add both classes here, include getters/setters as well.